# onchange method not showing text after using substring javascript

Tags: javascript

Somehow there is a problem when I use the substring in javascript. I'm trying to take the last 2 letters out of a 4 letter value and print in out in the div with id=text.

**This works without using substring**

```
$("#departureroute").change(function () {
    var value = (this.value);
    $("#test").text(value);
}).change();
```

**This does not work, using substring**

```
    $("#departureroute").change(function () {
    var value = (this.value);
    var res = value.substring(2, 2);
    $("#test").text(res);
}).change();
```

Any ideer what is happening?

Comment: can u pls post a fiddle?

Comment: `value.substring(2, 4);` You start and stop at the second character. So won't show anything. You can also use `value.substring(2);` to get everything after the second character. The first character is 0!

Comment: Well.. I see I used the C# syntax of the substring.. new to javascript so sorry if this was an easy answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Per the manual, the substring method takes the index of the beginning of the substring and index of the end of the substring.  The second argument is optional and will go to the end of the string if not provided.  So change it to:

```
$("#departureroute").change(function () {
    var value = (this.value);
    var res = value.substring(2);
    $("#test").text(res);
}).change();
```